# Position images on an image automatically as per Device Screen Size

Tags: android, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have a bigger image, on which I have placed smaller images on specific positions. When I run my application on different devices, the smaller images get misplaced from their specified positions. Following is the code. Please suggest a solution.

```
       <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
            <img id="m1" src="images/MTsupermarket.jpg" width="600" height="500" style="float:left; display:inline; margin-left:200px">
            <div style="position: absolute;top:112px;left:387px;">
                <a href="#options" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="flow"><img class="img1" src="images/cctvleft.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute;top:205px;left:460px;">
                <img src="images/area1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute;top:268px;left:576px;">
                <img src="images/area2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute;top:300px;left:676px;">
                <img src="images/area3.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that overlapping images with Android layouts is very hard to execute.

One thing I would suggest is scaling all the images and placing them in appropriate folders and using

```
"wrap_content"
```

for length and widths.  I would not set the absolute position (absolute layouts are deprecated) I would rather try to set the margins.